# Reproduce CSS kbd style in WPF? (box-shadow, border-radius, text-shadow)

Tags: c#, css, wpf

Im looking to create a hotkey page in WPF where I display a graphical representation of all the available hotkeys in my application. Rather than using icons because I cant find a good set that includes the Home key for example I would like to use a similar style as StackOverflow.

Im trying to copy and apply the following style:

<kbd>F4</kbd>

The CSS is:

```
kbd {
    padding: 0.1em 0.6em;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 0px 2px #FFF inset;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0.1em;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    line-height: 1.4;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I cant seem to find a way to reproduce the box-shadow (especially two), border-radius and text-shadow.

Alternatively if someone knows a good complete icon set for keyboard keys that would work.

This is what I currently have, but it looks nowhere near what it should:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Background="#FFF7F7F7"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="3" Color="#33000000" Direction="270"/>
    </Border.Effect>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="3" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        </Border.Effect>
        <TextBlock Padding="1.1 6.6" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" Foreground="#FF333333">HOME</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

[image: current look]

Comment: For the border radius, use `Border` control; for the box shadow use a `DropShadowEffect` on the border, and for the text shadow a `DropShadowEffect` on the text.

Comment: How would I achieve the double DropShadowEffect, I tried this but could only add one of them. Would I have to use two Border controls inside eachother?

Comment: Note that the second box shadow is an inset shadow, so it is rendered *inside* the box. You can probably solve that the easiest way by just having another border around the text inside.

Comment: Yeh thats what I though, ill give it a go!

Comment: Ive updated the original post with what I currently have, but it looks nowhere near what it should. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Background="#FFF7F7F7"
        BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC" CornerRadius="3">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="0" Direction="270" Opacity="0.2"/>
    </Border.Effect>
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="3">
        <TextBlock Padding="1.1 6.6" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" Foreground="#FF333333">
            <TextBlock.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Color="White" Direction="270" ShadowDepth="1"/>
            </TextBlock.Effect>
            HOME
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

Comment: It looks much better however still looks much different from what it looks like on this website. Here there is a dark shadow outside and a light shadow inside. Ill add a picture of your code to the original post

Comment: If you put it on a *light* background (or change the website’s background to be dark too), then you will see that it’s pretty much the same.